# Identity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint linear operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$ for which  $T^3 = I$ (the identity operator).
Prove that $T = I$.

What I'm thinking: $ T^3 = I   \Rightarrow   \lambda^3 = 1   \Rightarrow   \lambda = 1$ because self adjoint has only real eigenvalues.
Since $\lambda = 1$ we can then find eigenvectors $T(v) = \lambda v  \Rightarrow  T(v) = v$ which holds only if $T$ is an identity transformation.

However I feel that's very vague and I'm missing something.

Comment: Your argument is essentially correct. You just need to prove that $T(v) = v$ for any $v\in V$ and not just if $v$ is an eigenvector. But this is straightforward. Just observe that for any self-adjoint operator, there is a basis consisting of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

$T$ is self-adjoint, so it is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues. As you have shown, the only possible eigenvalue for $T$ is $1$. Thus, the diagonalization of $T$ has the form
$$
T = PIP^{-1} = PP^{-1} = I.
$$
So, $T = I$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

"which holds only if $T$ is an identity transformation" This is, of course, incorrect.

We can take advantage of the fact that that by the finite-dimensional spectral theorem, $V$ has an orthonormal basis such that the matrix of $T$ relative to this basis is a diagonal matrix with entries in the real numbers.

It follows from this and from your remark that there is only $1$ on the diagonal $T$. Hence $T=I$.